# call global object method result in null or not an object in IE8

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have the following JS, when it runs in IE8, I get the error: `ILL.TEST is null or not an object`, it works on other browsers through. any idea why this is happening? thanks for help in advance.

```
 //global name space
 var ILL={};

 ILL.TEST=(function(){
     function init(){
      }
     return { 
        init:init 
     };
 })();

 (function(){
      //error ILL.TEST is null or not an object
      ILL.TEST.init();
 })()
```

Comment: Try adding a console.log after ILL.TEST=(function(){... and one before ILL.TEST.init(); to check what fires first.

Comment: Your code works for me in IE8 Standards and Quirks mode. I used this page http://jsfiddle.net/sWtyt/

Comment: Have you tried adding a semicolor (`;`) after the `return` statement?

Comment: @thomas, the log before `ILL.TEST.init()` fire first;

Comment: @PPvG, I have the semicolon in my original code, I forgot to put here. have updated now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys, I have found out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I define the `ILL.TEST` after it is called. so this will be a problem:

```
 //global name space
 var ILL={};

 (function(){
    //error ILL.TEST is null or not an object
     ILL.TEST.init();
 })()

 //defining after this fn is called will result in null or not an object in IE8
 ILL.TEST=(function(){
     function init(){
      }
     return { 
       init:init 
     };
 })();
```

Comment: I don't understand. This won't work in any browser, including IE8.

Comment: Does not work. Here's another example page http://jsfiddle.net/RbFGZ/ This can not work because you use `TEST` before you define it. Here is an example page with try/catch. http://jsfiddle.net/RbFGZ/1/

Comment: you are right, it does not work in your example, but I have no idea why it worked before. :)